# Store File into mySql BLOB Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I whant to know if i and how i can store the whole file in my DB wich looks like this

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| file    | blob        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| USER_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| zname   | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date    | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| filetyp | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I managed to make a file upload Widget without any funktion behind it. It is possible to select a file and to press the Submit button. But thats it.

```
    $form = $this->beginWidget(
        'CActiveForm',
        array(
            'id' => 'upload-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
            'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        )
    );

echo $form->labelEx($model,'');
echo $form->fileField($model,'image');
echo $form->error($model,'image');
echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
$this->endWidget();
```

and now i dont know how to make a Controller Funktion that saves my file into my database. Where the "File"(DB filed) is the aktual kontent of the file the zname = the File name , date the aktual date of upload and filetype = the filetype.

For more information i had a question about downloading Files like that:
[Download link from Database BLOB with yii Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856284/download-link-from-database-blob-with-yii-framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what i did was add this to the view:

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

The Controller has $model devined as the USERZ module (DB)
the form that is been called looks like this

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'userz-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>


    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'file'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Submit' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

Also i added a if clause to the Contoller:

```
if(isset($_POST['USERZ']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['USERZ'];
            $model->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->beforeSave();
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
```

The bevore Save funktion is a funktion in the USERZ model wich looks like this and devines everything conzerning the file:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if($file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($this,'file'))
    {
        $this->zname=$file->name;
        $this->filetype=$file->type;
        $this->date=date('Y-m-d');
        $this->USER_id=Yii::app()->user->getId();
        $this->file=file_get_contents($file->tempName);
    }

return parent::beforeSave();
}
```